# Exporting Mailbox Attributes from Exchange 2010 to CSV using Exchange Management Shell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm currently looking at dumping some user contact details out of the exchange to import into another system which holds contact details (.csv).

The requirements are found when manually doing an export inside EMC 2010. However, I can't seem to get the PowerShell attribute names right.

The fields are **Company, Primary SMTP Address, First Name, Last Name, Title, Department, Phone, Recipient Type Details, Hidden from Address Lists**

I can only seem to find the **DisplayName** and **Primary email address**

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress,  @{Name=“EmailAddresses”;Expression={$_.EmailAddresses |Where{$_.HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled -eq $true} | ForEach-Object {$_.SmtpAddress}}} | Export-CSV C:\temp\smtp.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Is there a way to get a list of what all the Get-Mailbox attributes are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

```
Get-Mailbox <your primary smtp address> | format-list *
```

and see if that doesn't provide some clues.

Comment: Thankyou soo much for the prompt reply mjolinor.  Ive run it and........well, i thought this may be the case. EMC is pullying that data from somewhere else.  Is there a way to see what Powershell command EMC is doing when i do a manual export ?

Comment: I don't understand your response.  What data is the EMC pulling from "somewhere else"?

Comment: When i open Exchange Management Console , Goto Recipient Configuration, Then Mailbox.  I then Add the columns Listed above , and do a Export List and change the type to .csv from .txt.............    Sorry for the confusion, this is what i meant i was doing when i say "Manually inside EMC"

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood.  Are you wanting help with a Powershell script or with using the EMC?

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway mjolinor. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old, but adding a note. I think what he was asking is in the Exchange 2010 EMC you can drill down to Mailboxes and columns you can choose to view include Company.  But in the shell when you do "get-mailbox ID | FL" company is not one of the details.

My similar issue is I would like to use the get-mailbox command and pull a report that includes displayname, company, primarysmtpaddress, and emailaddresspolicyenabled.  Can't seem get all 4 of those fields in EMC or through shell

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.